# Bind or column index out of range, querying sqlite android table Error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to make a query to sqlite android to see for example how many users of a given username exist in a table. 
This is my function. I must specify that "getContentResolver() != null" and so is variable name.

```
private int findSelectedUser(String name) {
        int count = 0;

        try {
            String[] whereArgs = new String[] {name};
            String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { MyProvider.SETTINGS_USERNAME };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.SETTINGS_URI,
                    PROJECTION, MyProvider.SETTINGS_USERNAME , whereArgs, null);
            if (c != null) {
                count = c.getCount();
                c.close();
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
        System.out.println("Found something? " + count);
        return count;
    }
```

And after running i receive the error from the subject...and don't get it. In my where clause i have one column, in my where arguments one value.
Please help me make some sence of this, Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess that works:

```
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {name};
String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { MyProvider.SETTINGS_USERNAME };
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.SETTINGS_URI,
        PROJECTION, MyProvider.SETTINGS_USERNAME + "=?" , whereArgs, null);
if (c != null) {
    count = c.getCount();
    c.close();
}
```

If you want to use `whereArgs` you have to have the same amount of `?` in the `where` as you have items `whereArgs`

`whereArgs` will replace the `?` in the final database query

```
String where = "name = ? OR name = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
    "Peter",
    "Jim"
};
```

that results in `name = 'Peter' OR name = 'Jim'` for the query.

Btw: don't `catch(NullPointerException e)` - make your code safe so they can't happen